# MapTo for SqlProvider: no compile check for type mismatch

Tags: f#, type-providers

I'm trying to use the SQL Type Provider and I'm following the approach suggested in the [guidelines](http://fsprojects.github.io/SQLProvider/core/mappers.html).

### Compile vs runtime errors

I've noticed that the `.MapTo<'T>` convenience method is introducing **runtime** type-cast exceptions instead of anticipating the type checks at **compile** time.

Let's say we have a generic

```
let sel = r.MapTo<Selection>()
```

and compare the above with a simpler, but longer *property by property* assignment

```
sel.PacketNum <- r.PacketNum
```

In the latter case I get a safer and more helpful compile error, like for example:

> error FS0001: This expression was expected to have type `int` but here has type `int64`

Am I missing something about the `.MapTo<'T>` behaviour at compile vs runtime? Is this done *by or against design*?

### Fluent mapping and DB type assignment

I also wonder if there is the possibility (other frameworks provide such features) to

- set the mapping with a property attribute or similar (what if the column name is `packets` instead of `packet_num`)?
- set a different correspondence between a .Net type and a DB type (`INTEGER` to `int` instead of `INT` to `int`)?

or why it is not needed

Comment: what kind of database are you using?

Comment: @s952163 This happened while reading from a SQLITE db v3, in that case I believe there is no difference between INT and INTEGER on db side for a non-key column. I'm also using Microsoft SQL Server 2016 and Sybase ASE. I usually revert to a light orm package to separate the code from the db layer. Indeed I generated the sqlite tables from the model types by a feature of such orm library: see [here my F# setup](https://github.com/giuliohome/SqliteFromModel), shared on [linq2db](https://github.com/linq2db/linq2db/issues/721)

Comment: Aside from sqlite, both in [Sybase](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc38151.1510/html/iqrefbb/X315932.htm) `INT` or `INTEGER` is a signed 32-bit integer and in [Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/olap.102/b14346/dml_datatypes002.htm) `INTEGER` is a whole number in the range of (-2`**`31) to (2`**`31)-1 so again the `int` mapping suggested by linq2db appears more correct than the `int64` inferred by SQLProvider.